# Implementing notification for android and ios

Tags: android, ios, notifications

I have been working on an app in android and iOS that will be used for internal discussion in an organization. The are individual discussion boards for each department and also general organization-wide discussion board.

I wish to implement notification for the app and was looking for some advise.

Below is a scenario to give a clear picture of what I am looking to do:
1. Each user has a unique login and few departments associated to his/her login.
2. There are a few admin users who have access to all departments boards
3. Notification for something posted on a department board should be displayed only to users of that departments and admin users.

What should be the best way to implement this.

All my webservices are implemented in php and mysql.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I implemented  [Azure push notifications](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-javascript-backend-ios-get-started-push/) in Android and IOS app.If you want to work with  back-end service,azure notification is the best way to do it.You can send notification to specific user with tags.And a lot of another features.

Just do the steps by reading tutorials carefully.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am using Linux Hosting, should using Azure be a problem here.